# How to crawl magnet links with Apache Nutch and Solr so that they're available in Solr query results?

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch, magnet-uri

I made myself familiar with crawling with Apache Nutch and Solr, but realized that while HTTP and HTTPS links are available in Solr query results in the `content` field magnet links are not. I adjusted `conf/regex-urlfilter.txt` to be

```
-^(file|ftp|mailto):

# skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
# for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
-\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
#-[?*!@=]

# skip URLs with slash-delimited segment that repeats 3+ times, to break loops
-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/

# for linuxtracker.org
+^https?://*linuxtracker.org/(.+)*$
#+^magnet:\?xt=(.+)*$
    # causes magnet links to be ignored/not appear in content field
+^magnet:*$

# reject anything else
-.
```

and don't see why magnet links shouldn't be included inside `content`. As you can see, I'm investigating this using http://linuxtracker.org which e.g. has the magnet link magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ETDW2XT7HJ2Y6B4Y5G2YSXGC5GWJPF6P on http://linuxtracker.org/?page=torrent-details&id=24c76d5e7f3a758f0798e9b5895cc2e9ac9797cf.

After crawling with `bin/crawl` there're magnet links when querying Solr as follows in `pysolr`:

```
solr = pysolr.Solr(solr_core_url, timeout=10)
results = solr.search('*:*')
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

I'm using Apache Nutch release-1.13-73-g9446b1e1 and Solr 6.6.1 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: What do you expect crawling the magnet link should result in?

Comment: The purpose is to have a list of all magnet links on a site/domain to do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer magnet links are not "normal" links and not supported out of the box by Nutch.

Long answer:

The configuration that you've changed get's applied after the links are extracted, in this case, if you're using `parse-html` the parse plugin try to evaluate if the [possible outlink is a valid link](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/parse-html/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/html/DOMContentUtils.java#L438) this basically just creates a `java.net.URL`.

`java.net.URL` on the other hand doesn't support magnet links out of the box, according to the javadocs:

> Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist on the search path :
>
> ```
>  http, https, ftp, file, and jar
> ```

If you're using `parse-tika` [something similar is happening](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/parse-tika/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/tika/DOMContentUtils.java#L412).

> One option could be to have your custom parser that handles this for you, keep in mind that in any case, you wouldn't want to follow (have as outlinks) the magnet links because Nutch would not be able to process those links.

If you only want to have the links indexed in Solr/ES (for search), then you could write your own `HtmlParseFilter` and add those links in a separated field for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I'll guess I'll wait before the source root is [migrated to maven](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2292) since the build process of plugins should then be more straightforward than [with ant](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample-1.2).

Comment: Glad the helped, honestly writing a plugin right now (even with `ant`) is not very difficult.